# Match Div Heights That Aren't In A Row And Are Nested A Bunch

Tags: html, css

Age old question, but potentially with a twist. I have 3 divs with varying amounts of content and I need them to be the same height. The kicker though, I'm using a CMS and this has their HTML structure is all sorts of weird. They aren't on a row, and they each have like 6 container divs.

This is basically what we're looking like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top-div">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <!-- content... -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

repeat...
```

**CSS:**

```
.top-div {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 33%;
}
```

Do I have options here?

**Remember:** *I can't change the HTML*

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5csorg73/

Comment: Why you don't give them the fixed height. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/5csorg73/2/)

Comment: You say you can't change the HTML but you realize also that this will be a mess in small devices?

Comment: @Franco - Agreed, but I believe they have media queries in place. It looks like it adjusts for small devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, include this script:

https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

And with one row in Javascript, you can add the same height at all div in the row

```
$('.class-name').matchHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
.top-div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;  
  margin: 2% 0.5%;
  width: 30%;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

.top-div * {
    display: inline-block;  
}

.button {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  text-align: center;
  height:20px;
}

div div div div div{
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `vertical-align:top;` to your divs and fixed height.